# Exposing member variables methods in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a simple `Object-Components` design. Something like:

```
class Object1 : public Object
{
    Component1 _comp1;
    Component2 _comp2;
    ...
    ComponentN _compN;
};
```

Is it possible to expose as `public:` methods of `Objects1` some methods from `ComponentK` without creating a method in `Object1` that calls internally `ComponentK` method?

I need a simple way of doing this because it's quite annoying to write a function every time I want to expose some `ComponentK` method.

Comment: if `_compK` and the method you want to call are both public why not `obj1instance->_compK.method()` ?

Comment: @msam because the `_compK` are private?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not directly, no. You could use private inheritance to inherit from the components instead of aggregating them (note that private inheritance does not express **is-a**), and then publish some of their member functions by `using`. Something like this:

```
class Object1 : public Object, private Component1, private Component2, ..., private ComponentN
{
public:
  using Component1::function1();
  using Component1::function2();
  ...
  using ComponentN::functionM();
};
```

I'm not saying it's necessarily the best way to do it, but it's *a* way.

Comment: Note that although private inheritance implies a **has-a** instead of a **is-a** relationship, the `Component*` classes are part of the interface because clients of `Object1` need to know about them. You can't use e.g. the [PIMPL](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_100/) idiom.

Comment: It is not really a *has-a* relationship, as you inherit the object into the private area of the class. It is a mix between has-a and is-a, better refered to as implemented-in-terms-of.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a pointer to the members; the pointer will be owned by the caller and can be deleted without affecting the class member:

```cpp
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class Member {
    private:
        int size = 10;
    public:
        int getSize() {
            return size;
        };
};

class MemberContainer {
    private:
        Member member;
    public:
        Member * getMember () {
            return &member;
        };
};

int main()
{
  MemberContainer memberContainer;
  Member * memberPtr = memberContainer.getMember();
  std::cout << memberPtr->getSize() << std::endl;
  memberPtr = nullptr;
  delete memberPtr;
  Member * anotherMemberPtr = memberContainer.getMember();
  std::cout << anotherMemberPtr->getSize() << std::endl;
}
```

This will output:

```
10
10
```